# OBML file format

Tags: opera

Opera mini browser can save HTML pages in OBML (Opera Binary Markup Language) format for offline browsing. I am wondering if I can convert a HTML file to OBML format and save in my phone for later viewing.

For doing so, I need details about the OBML format, which seems to be undocumented. Do you know more details on this OBML format?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working way to save/open OBML files on your PC

- http://java4me.blogspot.com/2008/01/opera-mini-as-pc-browser-big-screen.html
- http://my.opera.com/opera.mini/forums/topic.dml?id=234030
- [Opera MicroEmulator](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://forum.mobile-review.com/showthread.php%3Fp%3D1354422&sa=X&oi=translate&resnum=1&ct=result&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dopera%2Bmini%2Bmicroemulator%2Bmobile-review.com%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DG)

Answer (score 2):

I reverse-engineered several OBML format versions and wrote a Python [OBML to HTML converter](https://nullroute.eu.org/:/obml-parser) along with [format documentation](https://nullroute.eu.org/:/obml-format). Generating OBML files might be more difficult, however, as it requires an actual HTML layout engine (all OBML elements are pixel-positioned rects).

Answer (score -2):

Nothing yet about OBML.
If the HTML is small in size you can simply upload the HTML to a file host or webspace, then access it using Opera mini then save it as OBML.